# If n belongs to set a and m belongs to set b repeat some steps, How do this in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements

We can do this in Java and similar languages:

```
for (int i=0, int j=3; i<=2 && j<=5;i++,j++){
    do some repetive task until the condition becomes false...
}
```

How might one keep these two conditions based on two different sets (suppose two
arrays whose indexes can be used as i and j) in condition block?

Comment: thanks Michael for editing.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

explicit iteration is kinda looked down upon in ruby as poor expression of thought. Usually there is a better way to achieve the desired goal.

That said, here's is best way I know of to iterate many variables:

```
i, j, k = 0, 3, 7
while i <= 2 && j <= 5 && k <= 100

  # code here

  i, j, k = [i, j, k].map(&:next)
end
```

You can also do it a little messier

```
i, j = -1, 2
while( (i += 1) <= 2 && (j += 1) <= 5 )

  # code here

end
```

**Edit:** If you want to go from 0 to 2, and 3 to 5, this works:

```
(3..5).each_with_index do |j, i|
  # code
end
```

Comment: first solution you have suggested is obvious and already have done that way...actually i was trying to do like:
 list=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
 (0..2,3..5).each do |i,j|
  do some task using i and j
 end
but ruby is not accepting this code as legal, can you suggest me something like this that runs with no error?